# d3.js image x and y attribute

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js, transition

I want to append an image to a div#photo and give it a x and a y attribute using d3.js, so that I can create a slide-in-from-the-left transition for the image. But it looks like x and y attribute do not apply to image elements? How would I achieve the transition effect with the image?

```
d3.select('#photo').append('img')
    .attr('src','images/1.jpg')
    .attr('width',500)                  
    .attr('height',300)
    .transition().attr('x', 100)
    .transition().attr('y', 200);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "it depends". You can use margins, padding, transform, left/right/top/bottom (in case of absolute positioning), etc.

Here's an example ([demo available](http://jsfiddle.net/90v2wrpx/1/)) with margins:

```
d3.select('#photo').append('img')
    .attr('src','http://google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png')
    .attr('width',100)                  
    .attr('height',50)
    .transition()
    .duration(3000) // 3 seconds
        .style('margin-left', '200px')
        .style('margin-top', '200px');
```